# What is the linear series $|mL|$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I am studying complex geometry and I am trying to find out what is the definition of the linear series $|mL|,$ where $L$ be a line bundle over a compact Kahler manifold $X^n.$

In particular, I know that this linear series is a series of divisors, but I cannot find the definition anywhere.

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: $|mL|$ is the complete linear system corresponding to the line bundle $L^{\otimes m}.$ Sometimes a line bundle and its corresponding divisor is denoted by the same notation. In that case we write $L^{\otimes m}$ as $mL$ (first one as line bundle and the second one as divisor). In the particular case, when $L=K,$ the canonical divisor, $|mK|$ or $|K^{\otimes m}|$ is called $m$-th pluricanonical series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for a given divisor $D$, the system $|D|$ is the space of all effective divisors equivalent to $D$. In this case, given a line bundle $L$, what you wrote is just the system corresponding to $mL$, the $m^{th}$ tensor power of $L$ with itself. Note that when you look at divisors from the point of view of line bundles over a compact Kahler manifold, the linear system has an interpretation as a projective space of holomorphic sections.

In general, if you're looking at algebraic geometry from the complex point of view, the main reference is Griffiths and Harris: *Principles of Algebraic Geometry*. I believe this question is discussed in their "Divisors and Line Bundles" section.